# Github Action Cypress Run silently fails on test errors

Tags: cypress, github-actions

Using Github action to run Cypress e2e tests but when tests fail the job still passes.

```
name: E2E
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths-ignore: [ '**.md' ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 8-20 * * *'

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        continue-on-error: false
        with:
          record: true
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
```

[image]

Reason I would like job to fail is to get notified either via Github job failing or with a slack notification like this

```
  - uses: 8398a7/action-slack@v3
    if: job.status == 'failure'
    with:
      status: ${{ job.status }}
      fields: repo
      channel: '#dev'
      mention: here
      text: "E2E tests failed"
    env:
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an `if: ${{ failure() }}` at the end?

I ended up creating my own curl request which notifies Slack when anything fails on a specific job. Adding it to the end worked for me.

```
name: E2E
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths-ignore: [ '**.md' ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 8-20 * * *'

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        continue-on-error: false
        with:
          record: true
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
+
+      - name: Notify Test Failed
+        if: ${{ failure() }}
+        run: |
+         curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data "{\"type\":\"mrkdwn\",\"text\":\".\n❌ *Cypress Run Failed*:\n*Branch:* $GITHUB_REF\n*Repo:* $GITHUB_REPOSITORY\n*SHA1:* $GITHUB_SHA\n*User:* $GITHUB_ACTOR\n.\n\"}" ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```